# How to group multiple rows with different column values in one single row

Tags: sql, oracle

Ex:
My data looks like below:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
Data1   10      30
Data2   20      40
Data3   30      50
Data4   40      60
```

The output should be like:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
Data    100     180
```

It should sum up all the values and display a single row

Comment: Can you show a larger sample data table?  Will you always have just one record in the result set, or could there be more than one?

Comment: Yes..the record set will always have one record

Comment: The two answers given below both seem to fit your needs then.

Comment: I knew that answer..summing up first and then Hardcoding the value as required into the first column.What i was trying to achieve is: decode the different set of values into one value such as Data.Column1 is table field and not a dynamic column

Answer (score 2):

> It should sum up all the values and display a single row

You need to use **SUM** as an aggregate.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da56f/1) for working demo.

```
SQL> SELECT 'data' col1, sum(column2) col2, sum(column3) col3  FROM t;

COL1       COL2       COL3
---- ---------- ----------
data        100        180
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Regular expression to capture the text only, in series.

```
SELECT regexp_substr(column1,'[^[:digit:]]+',1) col1, 
       sum(column2) col2,
       sum(column3) col3 
FROM t
group by regexp_substr(column1,'[^[:digit:]]+',1);
```

**Example Output:**

```
Data    100     180
Hello   100     180
```

Just in case you want a (limited)generic solution.